# Update field on database with checkbox with submit button on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I wanna update field, with true or false. But when it, already false or true, and I update it with its reverse, it doesn't fill the updated one. How it can be and the solution ?

Here is my code on the view :

```
<div>
  <%= check_box_tag "group[group_type][]", {:class => "checkbox"} %><%= " show" %>
</div>
```

Here is my code on controller

```
def update
    params[:group][:group_type] ||= []

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.update_attributes(params[:group])
        format.html { redirect_to admin_group_path(@group), :notice => 'Group updated' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit"}
      end
    end
end
```

when I checked the checkbox, the database fills false, when it unchecked, still false, when it is not given anything, not yet do check or unchecked, it is nil. And how to give it a default checked or unchecked according to database ?

Any idea? Thanks for ur help.

Solution :

changed in the view like this :

```
<%= f.check_box :group_type %>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you should answer your question instead of adding the solution to your question

Comment: yes I am ...I have already done it :) tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
<%= f.check_box :group_type %>
```